# How do I rename a category in the menu bar only?

Tags: plugins, categories

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before, but I couldn't find it via search.

I'd like to do:

```
Full Category Name -> Text in Menu Bar
Exercise Tips -> Tips
Reviews of Exercise Equipment -> Reviews
Industry News -> News
```

So the menu bar looks like:
`Tips | Reviews | News`

But when you're in the actual category, it shows the full title. What I need is a "Navigation Name" field in the category setup screen. Is there a way to do this, perhaps with a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is pretty simple and straightforward: when you set up your menu (under **Appearance > Menu**) you will find out you can add *Categories* there.

After adding them, click on the down-pointing arrow on the right of the navigation element, it will give you the possibility to change the *Label*, while keeping the *Original* visible to you, so you remember what it actually refers to.

In order to make the Menu you just created appear in your theme, you have to look at the [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function. You can take to approaches to display your menu:

1. Either you [**register your menu location**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) in your theme, and then fill up the menu in your dashboard. In this case you will use the `$theme_location` argument of the function.
2. Or you take the opposite direction: create a menu in your dashboard and use it in your theme, using the `$menu` argument, which accepts `id`, `slug` or `name`.

Comment: Ahhh, I was looking in the wrong place. So once I add a new menu, how do I tell the theme to use my "Main Navigation" menu?

Comment: @Nick Be so kind as to ask this comment as a new question (or even better, research it first) and accept this answer as correct - it does answer the initial one, doesn't it?

Comment: The question was how to make alternate category text appear in the top navigation bar. This is the first step, creating a custom menu, but a second step is required to make it actually appear. So technically, this answer is correct, but incomplete. For the next person who has this question, it would be good to have a complete answer for it. I feel that the second part of the answer should go here as well, since it's a necessary step to answer the original question that was asked.

Comment: Here you go, edited my answer.